# Linux noob question - How do I update a program built from source?

Tags: linux, centos, installation, make

When I build a program from source (CentOS), How do I go about updating it to a new version? Can I just run the make && make install again with the same configure options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you get the new source, check the README or INSTALL files. Often there will be a section about upgrading. If there is not, doing a make && make install should work.

Answer (score 3):

99% of time, just download the source of the new version (or a patch), build and install.

Answer (score 3):

This is where GNU Stow can be useful. I've been using this tool for years to keep my OS clean. This is a package manager for programs installed from source. Here's how it works. First, I have one single directory where I keep all such programs, `/usr/local/stow`. Inside it, there are directories for each program. When I compile programs from source, I use option `--prefix=/usr/local/stow/program-name`. When `make install` is done, the executable files are installed under `/usr/local/stow/program-name/bin`, libraries are found in `/usr/local/stow/program-name/lib`, etc. Then I run `cd /usr/local/stow` and `sudo stow program-name`. The last command creates links from `/usr/local/stow/program-name/bin` to `/usr/local/bin/`, from lib to `/usr/local/lib`, etc. So, all files that belong to one program are located in one directory.

When I want to delete or update the program, I run `sudo stow -D program-name` to delete the links and remove the directory. Now, the system is clean and I can install the new version.